# Flexbox not taking the full height of the wrapper

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a problem with my side flexbox, which is not taking the full height of the site.

```
.aside-1 {
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 18px;
        flex: 1;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

I tried to set the height to 100% but with no effect. Here is the site in full: http://jsbin.com/yujoqaxubi/edit?output

I tried also to add

```
position:absolute; bottom:0
```

But it just breaks the site.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you have 2 `.wrapper`s there, decide for one first. this maybe why it happens

Comment: Yeah, you do not need to add `height: 100%;` in your `<aside>` element. flex-container default  value in `align-items` property is `stretch` taking all the available space in the cross axis. Remove the `height` property in all your media queries and see how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.aside-1 {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    flex: 1;
    height: auto;
}
```

will do the tricks

Comment: Ok, now it causes another problem. The aside flexbox ends where the second article starts. It is working great if I write the whole content in one article.

Comment: place your articles into a div along with the style `{ flex: 1 60%; order: 4; }` , remember to clean up the flexbox properties for you articles.